# Windows form application can't be closed normally

Tags: c#, exit

I have problem when closing the windows form application. I need to know is it always called `private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)` if I press **X** button on the form and if I just click to shut down computer?

Anyone neither of this times form is not closed as normally. I always have screen to press **End now**

I have connecting to the databases when form is closing, and copying some records to another database. Is that maybe the problem? Form is closing to fast and sql commands can't finish?

I have tried `Enviroment.Exit(0)`, `Application.Exit()`. Nothing seems to be working correctly.

How to make it do all the sql and then quit?

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //close database connection
            if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                Con.Close();
            info.Dispose();

            //last check for local database
            try
            {
               // database queries and so on....

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeToLogFile(ex.Message);
            }
            // exit
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: have you tried the above code _without_ Environment.Exit() ?

Comment: @alexm: Good point. Might be an infinite recursion due to the `Environment.Exit` attempting to close the form again.

Comment: Try not implementing the `FormClosing` event and then add pieces of your code back in to isolate the issue.

Comment: Project + Properties, Build tab, change Platform Target to "AnyCPU".  You'll now get a proper notification of an unhandled exception on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: @alexm yes I have tried without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE (based on your last comment):

```
private const int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
private const int WM_CANCELMODE = 0x1f;
private bool shutdownRequested = false;

...

protected override void WndProc(ref Message ex)
{
    if (ex.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
    {
        Message MyMsg = new Message();
        MyMsg.Msg = WM_CANCELMODE;
        base.WndProc(ref MyMsg);
        this.shutdownRequested = true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.WndProc(ex);
    }
}

...

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false; // optional
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false; // optional
    Task db = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DBUpdate();
    Task.WaitAll(db); // you can have more tasks like the one above
    if (this.shutdownRequested)
        Process.Start("shutdown.exe","-s");
}

private void DBUpdate()
{
    // write your db code here
}
```

I believe that this will work.

Comment: so in this second option I put my code inside this while loop? bellow the `thread`?

Comment: give me a minute to update my answer. my bad for confusing you.

Comment: okay this is sort of working. I am exiting an application but my program is still running in the task manager

Comment: And it will as long you have pending stuff within your application aka the database update. When the task is finished your application should be removed from task manager.

Comment: my application will be closing when you shut down pc, then it will cut it automatically?

Comment: Absolutely not when there are pending things to do with the database. If you want it to close automatically then you have to forget the database stuff at closing the form because there is no guarantee that it will be full and committed (that makes it a very bad practice).

Comment: hmm... now you put me way behind :( I will have app that will be on the pc but the pc will be in the "kiosk" mode. So what do you suggest. What would be the best approach?

Comment: the above function is called with `Process.Start("shutdown.exe","-s");`

Comment: what do you say about the above answer?

Comment: It is called with condition in case there was a message from os to the application for shutdown.

Comment: I have some invalid arguments when declaring `base.WndProc(MyMsg);`

Comment: I see. Change "base.WndProc(MyMsg);" to "base.WndProc(ref MyMsg);"

Comment: should this line be changed too? `base.WndProc(ex);`

Comment: hello? should the last line be with the `ref`?

Comment: please take a look at this question as you answered me first one. I have a problem with this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235731/windows-process-cant-close-my-application

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone neither of this times form is not closed as normally. I always have screen to press End now

Are you saying you want the application to automatically shutdown if the computer is restarted or shut down?

If so, just hook up an event to the *Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding* event.

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);

void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Run your application shut down code here...
    }
```