# Windows process can't close my application

Tags: c#, winforms, process, task, shutdown

I have a windows form application which is writing bunch of stuff in the database. Now some time ago I was asking for the solution of how to be sure that all requests (writing to the database) has been done before windows form is closed.

The reason why am I doing this is because it will be a self standing application which has an automatic shut down and therefore I need to be able to finish all my writing and reading from the database and be sure when I am closing form that all the job is done.

Before I tried this solution I had a problem of cutting a connection when writing in the database because of a form closing.

Now the problem is that when I have a shut down process my windows form application won't close, so after some time it just cuts of the electricity which is not what I need.

Here is the code, and please tell me what is wrong with it? I need to close the form when program is sure that no task is working in the background.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
      // this.Visible = false; // optional
      // this.ShowInTaskbar = false; // optional
      Task db = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DBUpdate());
      Task.WaitAll(db);
      if (this.shutdownRequested)
            Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-s");
 }

 protected override void WndProc(ref Message ex)
 {
      if (ex.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
      {
           Message MyMsg = new Message() { Msg = WM_CANCELMODE };
           base.WndProc(ref MyMsg);
           this.shutdownRequested = true;
      } else {
           base.WndProc(ref ex);
      }
 }
```

EDIT:

I just realized that this is working when I click the **X** button and form starts to close, but when pc goes into the shutdown phase then its not. Any idea? Maybe I need to change a event on something else and not on the **FormClosing** ? One more thing. I have saved a priority of the application process as a real-time process.

Comment: Would it not be better to call `shutdown.exe` with argument `-a`, so effectively abort, then you can call shutdown when you are ready.

Comment: So the problem is that the FormClosing event is not triggered when Windows is shutting down?

Comment: There's a bunch of unnecessary code in the snippet.  No point in using a Task and then wait for it, no point in running shutdown.exe.  How long does DBUpdate() take?  If it is more than a couple of seconds then you can't make it work.

Comment: Hmm I don't know how much it takes actually. But I think that few seconds is really enough for that request to finish. As I edited my question, when I click the X button Formclosing event is triggered but I can't check if it is triggering when I restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process takes more than a couple of seconds, the OS will kill it during a shutdown. Your only hope is to abort the shutdown, do the work and call it again.

*Your process only takes a couple of seconds, and is dependent on the instance of the Form, so this solution does not create a new thread to do the work in. So you should `hide` the form to prevent use interaction, as the main thread will be locked up while this process is run.*

If a shutdown event tries to close the application. The application will abort the shutdown. It will need `administrator` privileges to be able to do this though.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool _isClosing;
        private bool _isRunningUpdate;
        private bool _isShutdown;
        private Timer timer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
            timer = new Timer();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
            {
                // Abort Shutdown
                Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-a");
                _isShutdown = true;
            }

            if (!_isRunningUpdate && _isClosing) return;

            // Set isClosing to true
            _isClosing = true;

            if (!_isRunningUpdate)
            {
                _isRunningUpdate = true;
                timer.Tick += DbUpdate;
                timer.Interval = 500;
                timer.Enabled = true; 
                timer.Start();
            }

            // Cancel current close request
            e.Cancel = true;

            // Optional Hide() --- could display message
            // Hide();
        }

        private void DbUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            _isRunningUpdate = false;
            if (_isShutdown)
                Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-s -t 10");
            if (_isClosing)
                Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it just cuts me off in the middle of the update and I am getting error window. In the first program that I wrote in the question then it waited for too long,  now its not waiting. And I need to be sure that everything is saved correctly.

Comment: I just checked it. When I click on the **X** button then program goes into the  DbUpdate() and I have some null exceptions as it is not waiting

Comment: I got it working here, I would need more specific details on error message you are getting to work out the issue. Are you running the app as Administrator?

Comment: SO doesn't like long conversations in comments. If you want meet me in the c# chat room and we debug the solution. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: well after some time trying I can live with that shutdown error :) I don't know if everything is done correctly and saved but program is shutting down :) Is there anything that can remove that shutdown.exe window?

Comment: I don't know perhaps you can kill the process by name (http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_kill_process_by_name) where name is "shutdown" but not sure